# OpenGL ES 2 importing a 3D model

Tags: android, opengl-es

I'm new to OpenGL ES 2 and I'm trying to load a model that I've created in blender into the program. I've found many tutorials on how to do this in ES version 1 using .obj files but none so far for ES 2. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: OpenGL does not handle model loading. You either have to use a library to get the file into the application or write an importer yourself (This part will be quite similar to what you will find for ES1).

Comment: BDL - I found an importer. But when I use that data in my code, i get the following error:-
Fatal signal 11 (SIGSEGV), code 2, fault addr 0x74662138 in tid 2205 (GLThread 163)